# "Was invented" or "Had been invented"?

Tags: passive-voice

Good afternoon! I have a question about using these two tense forms, which I've written above. There is a sentence:

> [B4] "Back in the days before the car **was/had been invented**, the only personal means of transport were the horse and the bicycle. The first cars got their power from steam and gas..."

What is the difference between "was" and "had been" in **this** sentence? Which one to use?[image]

Comment: Both "was" and "had been" work fine in this sentence.  The fact that some test asks you to choose which is "correct", only shows that the people who wrote the test only **think** they know English.

Comment: I agree with @Andrew, both "was invented" and "had been invented" sound fine, and have the same meaning (in this example).

Comment: I agree witg Andrew and Joe that both are possible. I don't kniw why but I'd go with **was invented**. There's no need for Past Perfect here.

Comment: @A.Smith  The question isn't whether there is a logical difference between them.  The question is which is *correct* in the given context.  Both are *correct*, the difference is whether you want to add a slight extra emphasis on the relationship between two actions.   If your teacher thinks we are wrong, then she can come here and post her opinion, and we can discuss.

Comment: I think this test was probably set by a non-native speaker (or at least, a poorly-educated one). I've never heard anyone refer to "the car" as having been ***invented*** - it's been a long drawn-out process of refinement. [There are many different types of automobiles - steam, electric, and gasoline - as well as countless styles.](https://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/auto.html) Which one would count as "the first ***real*** car"?

Comment: The word "car" is much older than the automobile. For example, take rail train cars. But assume for the moment that "the car" was invented at an identifiable time, and at that time, roller skates had not been invented. The word "before" in the test question renders the past perfect tense ("had been invented")  unnecessary and verbose. The short answer is that either "was invented" or "had been invented" is good enough, but "was invented" is better. I would strike "Back in the days," saying, "Before the car was invented, the only personal means of transportation were the horse and the bicycle,"

Comment: @JiveDadson  Yeah, exactly.  *Before* establishes the temporal relationship, making the perfect tense redundant.  It's still fine to use it, but there's no way I'd say it's *better* than the simple past.  In fact, I should write that up as the answer in case someone else, similarly misinformed, comes looking.

Comment: @Andrew - Done .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for the moment that "the car" (automobile) was invented at an identifiable time. The word "before" in the test question renders the past perfect tense ("had been invented") unnecessary and verbose.

**The short answer is that either "was invented" or "had been invented" is good enough, but "was invented" is possibly better, because of its brevity.**

Also for brevity, I would strike "Back in the days," saying, "Before the car was invented, the only personal means of transportation were the horse and the bicycle."

An example of a sentence in which the past perfect is necessary is, "When roller skates were first produced, the automobile had not been invented."

- *The word 'car' dates from around 1300. It means "wheeled vehicle." Before the automobile, there were other modes of personal transportation besides horses and bicycles. For example, roller skates were invented in the mid 1700's.*